# Fixing the Position of UIImage in Xcode

Tags: xcode, interface, interface-builder, uiimage

I am having a problem in overlapping two images which one of them is the  subview of the other. However, when running the program, the position of the subview image in IB and the Iphone simulator is difference.

May i know how to fix the position of my subview according to the IB?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the xib and click on the info.There is a tab called "viewIdentity".There you will find the alignment.Remove all the redmarks.